# How to set Python IDLE to use certain python version

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Windows 8.

Python version 2.7.3 have been installed on my computer together with another software.

Now I have installed python 3.3.5 and i want to use this version from now.
But everytime I run Python IDLE it runs version 2.7.3.
Even if I go to C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw and run idle.pyw it runs with the 2.7.3 version.

I thought that every python version install its own IDLE so I am quiet confused here.

When I run Hello world program from the console it runs using the version 3.3.5 I have checked that.

So what I need to do is to run IDLE using 3.3.5 version

Anybody knows what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each installation of Python comes with its own respective version if IDLE. I suggest you explore your Python installation folder, and find the version of IDLE you're looking for and create a shortcut to it, or add it to your environment variable list, so you can invoke a specific version from the command line.